# How to split file on basis of size without breaking last line of split file

Tags: linux

I have a big file and want to split the file on the basis of size.

For e.g.

Main file: 10 Mb and then I want to split it into 2 mb parts.
But the issue is if I use split -b it breaks the last line in part files. A small correction in size of splitted file is acceptable (to complete last line).

Comment: At least [GNU `split`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html#split-invocation) has a `-C` option for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the fix. I Used:

```
split -C "size" <filename>
```